# Entity Framework Seed method is not being called

Tags: database, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, code-first

We are using Entity Framework 4.4 and using migrations. The database already exists and we need to update it on regular basis. The seed method, however, is not being called and so lookup values are not being added.

The code looks as follow:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDbContext>
{
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
            SetSqlGenerator("System.Data.SqlClient", new OurSqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator());
        }

        protected override void Seed(KinectionDbContext context)
        {
            SeedLookupTables(context);
        }

        private static void SeedLookupTables(KinectionDbContext context)
        {
            context.Titles.AddOrUpdate(t => t.Value,
                new Title {Value = "Mr"},
                new Title {Value = "Mrs"},
                new Title {Value = "Miss"},
                new Title {Value = "Ms"},
                new Title {Value = "Dr"}
            );

            context.SaveChanges();
        }

}


public class MyDbContext : ObjectContext
    {
        public MyDbContext()
        {

        }

        static MyDbContext ()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<KinectionDbContext>(null);
        }

        public DbSet<Title> Titles { get; set; }

}
```

And we are calling:

```
Add-Migration Seed
```

But the migration comes up empty.

Does anyone has an idea why the Seed is cmot being called and why the additional values in the lookup table are not being detected?

Thanks
N

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Migrations Seed method

> runs whenever the Update-Database PowerShell command is
>   executed

You need to call `Update-Database` not `Add-Migration`

`Add-Migration` scaffolds a migration file containing commands to migrate the database to a new version. It is empty because there are no schema changes to make. You do not need to call `Add-Migration` before calling `Update-Database` if all you want to do is seed

References:

[Code first Db initialization strategies.](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/database-initialization-strategy-in-code-first.aspx)
[Code first migrations recommended reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621)
[Managed Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj554735)
[Database initializer and Migrations Seed methods](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/)

Comment: Thank you, that worked :). However, is there a way to get the sql script for the seeding?

Comment: update-migration returns a bag of errors because in my seed method I used files or other logic implementation