# Can an Entity Framework migration be run without performing the Seed

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I am using Entity Framework (version 6.1.3) - Code First - for my application.

The application is hosted on the Azure platform, and uses Azure SQL Databases.

I have a database instance in two different regions, and I am using the Sync Preview to keep the data in sync.

Since the sync takes care of ensuring the data is kept synchronised, when I run a migration, I'd like the schema changes and seed to happen in only one database, and the schema changes only (with no seed) in the other.

Is this possible with the EF tooling, or do I need to move the seeding out to a manual script?

Comment: in your production database, you don't want to run the seed script, right?

Comment: I would like the seed to run only against one database.  Then the Sync can take care of ensuring any newly seeded data is copied to the other database.

Comment: @BrendanGreen, check my answer in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28635377/ef6-run-update-database-command-without-seeds/28637291#28637291)

Comment: thanks @octavioccl, that pretty much outlines what the current capabilities are.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by spreading out your deployment.

if worker role 1 updates your database and seed
if after the sync worker role 2 connects to your other database it will see that the migration already took place.

One way to trigger this is to disable automatic migrations on all but 1 worker role. The problem is that you potentially have to deal with downtime/issues while part of your application landscape is updated/migrated but your database is still syncing.

(worker role can also be replaced by webjob , website etc )

Comment: I don't think that'd work.  Well, it'd work for the seed data, but I've set it up to **not** sync the migration table, as I would need to ensure that the schema changes are applied.  The desire is to be able to run the migration against both databases, but have the seed only execute on one of them.